# Ajax/JQuery id referencing over multiple table rows

Tags: mysql, ajax, jquery

Having problems with assigning a specific id to a varied list of items selected from a table so that the user can click on that item thus executing some Ajax/Jquery, etc.

```
/** this code had been cut, '$row' is required **/
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){  
    echo "<tr><td>
          <a id='event_add' title='Add Event' href='javascript:void(0)'>
          <img border='0' src='add_button.gif' width='25' height='25'/></a>
    </td></tr>";
}
```

Is it possible to have it like this and refer to the id easily using the following?

```
    $('#event_add').click(function(){
    var row = ($(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent()))-1;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "add_event.php",
        data: "row="+row+"&do=addEvent",
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function(result){
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function(result){
            alert(result);
        }
    });         
});
```

Any advice on this problem would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could print a row identifier into your output code.

```
/** this code had been cut, '$row' is required **/
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){  
    echo "<tr><td>
          <a class='event_add' data-rowid='" . $row['id'] . "' title='Add Event' href='javascript:void(0)'>
          <img border='0' src='add_button.gif' width='25' height='25'/></a>
    </td></tr>";
}
```

and then, in your function, row would be defined as

```
var row = $(this).attr('data-rowid');
```

Also, change your function assignment code to use a class selector as well.

```
$(".event_add").click(...)
```

Comment: peoples peoples peoples, please, if you want to use a custom attribute, please prefix it with `data-`, use `data-rowid` or something like that. Aside from being html5 supportive, it is a *lot* easier to read and understand

Comment: ofcourse it does, but just be aware that some html5 enthusiast might come for you in the middle of the night with a katana... ;)

Comment: True, but they won't find me because I'm cowering in the corner.

Comment: from the code segment you provided, 'row_id' returns undefined.. :S

Comment: I did make the assumption (perhaps incorrectly) that your database table has a column named "id". If you have a unique identifier in your table, replace "$row->id" with its name, ie, "$row->id_number", "$row->unique_identifier", etc.

Comment: um, Rob, you are using `mysql_fetch_array`, not `mysql_fetch_object`, so you have to do `$row['id']`, not `$row->id`... *that*, or I need some sleep :)

Comment: You're perfectly right, sorry... I'm tired too. :) I've been doing mostly Wordpress plugin work lately and it returns an object instead of an array. My apologies, I'll fix the original post.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I got there in the end! :D

Comment: /me waves from the corner. ;)

Comment: aha! and the katana strikes!!

Comment: oh well, lets hope the guy with the katana notices it :), also when using jQuery 1.4.2+, you can do `.data('rowid')` instead of `.attr('data-rowid')` :)

Answer (score 2):

why don't you use

`Class` instant of `id`

change

html

**id='event_add'** to **class='event_add'**

script

**$('#event_add')**
to
**$('.event_add')**